# Windows: Find out which process spawned another process

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, powershell, windows-command-prompt

I have a situation with processes a bit like below. We have 2 executables, foo.exe and bar.exe. bar.exe is always launched by foo.exe.
I want to know how to find out which bar.exe has been spawned by which foo.exe. It's probably very simple but cannot work it out.

```
Name      Pid

foo.exe   1
foo.exe   2
foo.exe   3

bar.exe   4
bar.exe   5
bar.exe   6
```

Happy for dos or powershell solutions.

Comment: What about showing only a bit of [research effort](http://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+find+parent+process)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `wmic process get Caption,ParentProcessId,ProcessId` for a list in command line. Or use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) from the [SysInternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) for a GUI option.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on the answer from @Lenniey, the following is a nicely formatted process list with the parent ID and a filter condition:

```
$IsSee = {$_.CommandLine -match 'd:\\' -or $_.Path -match 'd:\\'};
Get-WmiObject win32_process | where -FilterScript $IsSee | 
    select @{l='PID';e={$_.ProcessId}},@{l='PPID';e={$_.ParentProcessId}},
      @{l='#Thrd';e={$_.ThreadCount}},
      @{l='vmGB';e={[math]::round($_.VM/1gb,2)}},CommandLine | 
    Format-Table -wrap -auto
```

(in this case commands related to drive D:)